# Create object from class by string value

Tags: string, flash, actionscript-3, class

Is it possible to create an object from a class with a dynamic name? I have the name of the class in a string, but I want to create an instance of that class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
var classRef:Class = getDefinitionByName("YourClassIncludingPackage") as Class;
var newMc:YourClass = new classRef() as YourClass;
addChild(newMc);
```

Comment: You need to be aware that this class must be included in the application somewhere else in the normal manner.  `getDefinitionByName` takes the definitions from the ApplicationDomain at runtime, and so if that definition was not included in the compile elsewhere this code will fail.

Answer (score 2):

```
var cl:Class = getDefinitionByName ("my.class.name") as Class;
var instance:Object = new cl();
```

Make sure you've used the class at some time, though, otherwise its byte code won't be compiled into your program.

Comment: You can also force it by adding the includes compiler flag.